# Close ng-Bootstrap Modal on save

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

How can I close the ng-bootstrap modal once my save function has been successful?

Here's what I have so far:

```
save(form, activeModal) {
    this.goalsService.createNewGoal(this.team_id, form.value, this.date_created, this.date_modified)
      .subscribe(
        () => {
          form.reset();

          activeModal.dismiss('Successfully created Goal');

        },
        err => alert(`error creating goal ${err}`)
      );

  }
```

Comment: activeModal may have a 'close' method

Comment: You should show more code (ideally in a plunker) as from the snippet you've provided it is not clear what you are trying to do and what is not working. Most important part - is the `save` method inside a modal? Or outside of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a very simple fix. All I needed to do was change `activeModal.dismiss('Successfully created Goal');` to `this.activeModal.dismiss('Successfully created Goal');`

Answer (score 2):

At the time of opening modal using `NgbModal` service, it will return `NgbModalRef` instance.

Using returned instance we can close or dismiss modal.

```
loginModel : NgbModalRef;
constructor(private modalService:NgbModal) {}

onOpen(){
     this.loginModel =  this.modalService.open(content);
}

onSave(){
.
.
.
   (success)=>{
       this.loginModel.close();
   }
}
```